# Make full width for a non responsive site when browser resize

Tags: html, css

I have made a non-respnsive site using the below viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1400">
```

It is showing the desktop view on both desktop and mobile without any issues.

But when I resize the browser, the page goes beyond the screen horizontally. Which is the expected behaviour.

Is there some CSS or script which I can use to make the page full width when we resize the screen too so that the screen will show full width and height will decrease just like on mobile?

I used the below CSS to make it happen:

```
body {
    width: 100%;
}
```

But it breaks the layout when resizing the screen.

Can anyone point where I made the mistake?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want control on diffrent viewport you must be add this below meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: I don't want a responsive site. I want a fixed width site. So I have used fixed width in meta viewport. It is working fine on mobile too

Comment: you can use that meta tag I said and define a container class to main content and set max-width of it to 1400px

Comment: @Jituu     Has the problem been resolved?

Comment: No, unfortunately, the thing you have mentioned is still making the site responsive. You can check what I am suggesting from here: http://ifec.it2u.net/index1.html

Here I want to show the full width when the browser is resized horizontally

Comment: you must remove max-width property from html tag